# Implementing a countdown timer overlaying the activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-animation, countdowntimer, background-task

I have an activity that is evaluating the person singing in real-time against a reference track. What I want is that when the person clicks on the practice button, there is a countdown for 5 seconds over the screen with all the components on the screen deactivated. I also want to show the countdown on the screen. The idea is to have a transparent grey overlay on top of my `Activity` view and show the countdown on that.
I am thinking of implementing the logic with `AsyncTask` and `CountDownTimer` in the Android-SDK. What can be the best ways to achieve the visualization for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to achieve this without using a `CountDownTimer`. For this purpose I created a class extending the `AsyncTask` as follows:

```
    public class CountdownTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

    private ICountdownView mCountdownView;

    private static final String TAG = "CountdownTask";

    public CountdownTask(ICountdownView countdownView) {
        this.mCountdownView = countdownView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Code to set up the timer ...
        mCountdownView.initCountdownView();

    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        // setting the default number of steps ..
        int countdownSteps = 5;
        // reading the number of steps if mentioned in the parameters
        if (params.length >= 1 && params[0] != null) {
            countdownSteps = params[0];
        }

        // setting the default step duration in milliseconds ..
        int stepDur = 1000;
        // reading the step duration if mentioned in the parameters
        if (params.length >= 2 && params[1] != null) {
            stepDur = params[1];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < countdownSteps; i++) {
            publishProgress(countdownSteps - i);
            sleep(stepDur);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        mCountdownView.updateCountdownView(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);
        mCountdownView.destroyCountDownView();
    }

    private void sleep(int mDelay) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(mDelay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

For updating to UI, I have created an interface `ICountdownView`. Whichever activity has want a countdown needs to implement this interface and then initialize `CountdownTask` using `new CountdownTask(this)`, where `this` refers to the reference of the activity class. The interface `ICountdownView` is as follows:

```
    public interface ICountdownView {

    void initCountdownView();

    void updateCountdownView(int timeLeft);

    void destroyCountDownView();
}
```

In your activity, you implement all these methods by whatever animation you want. In my case, on `initCountdownView()`, I initialize a dialog with transparent background and no header. On each `updateCountdownView(int timeLeft)`, I show the time left on the dialog and animate it. On `destroyCountDownView()`, I `dismiss()` the dialog and proceed with whatever I need to do the next. Hope this helps!

PS: You can initiate the `CountdownTask` with the number of steps and the duration of each step mentioned in milliseconds like:

```
mCountdownTask.execute(5, 1000);
```

This above statement makes the countdown to execute in 5 steps with each step being 1000 milliseconds (1 second) long. This is also the default behavior of the `CountdownTask` in case the user does not supply with any arguments.

Answer (score 1):

go for `CountDownTimer`, as it provides out-of-box the ticking functionality:

```
new CountDownTimer ( 5000, 1000 ) {
  @Override 
  public void onTick( long millisUntilFinished ) {
    countDownView.setText( (int)( millisUntilFinished / 1000 ) + "sec left" );
  }

  @Override 
  public void onFinish() {
    overlay.setVisibility( GONE );
  }
}.start()
```

Comment: I am clear with this part. What I meant to ask was how to implement the View. For now, I am using `PopupWIndow` with a transparent background over my activity. I am implementing the `CountDownTimer` inside the `doInBackground()` method of a `AsyncTask`. I chose to do this because I wanted to separate this logic from my main Activity and reuse the same implementation of the countdown timer in other places as well. The problem I am getting now is that, it shows me a runtime exception `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`.

Comment: I wouldn't start a CDT out of AT, because both of them are running in threads so it would come to certain overhead. Then you have to take care of UI-thread: in an AsyncTask you can influence the main thread only in `onPre/PostProcess()` methods. On the other hand, you can generify your CDT-implementation by passing the overlay-view as a constructor argument into it

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for hinting on that. That helped !!